# How to cause delay before open keyboard?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am wondering how to cause delay of 1-2 seconds before open the keyboard.
I'm using this command for hide the bottom navigation and the status bar:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
```

and when I tap on `TextFormField` it's causing to lag.

All I need is to delay keyboard for 1 second and restore the `Overlays`.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to handle this.

You could add a listener to your TextField's TextEditingController()
 and run the code when it's appropriate.

[TextEditingController usage Flutter Cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes)

Intentionally adding lag to your app may not be a great solution. Try not to create new problems by solving problems.

Try to identify why this is causing a delay.

Have you tested on a physical device? Sometimes the Emulator or Simulator can produce lag if you're running many tasks or on an older machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a future!.

```
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).then((_) {
      // open keyboard
    });
```

Comment: The keyboard opens automatically once you click textformfield, is there a way to undo it and then use your method?